# What is the recommended way to group properties of a class?

Tags: angular

I have a class component with a series of properties that will be used in different context in the view. I would like to know the recommended way to group these properties to avoid, for example, putting any comment describing the context in which they will be used.

For example

```
// use in dashlet 1
property1: string;
property2: string;
property3: string;

// use in dashlet 2
property4: string;
property5: string;
```

I have tried using an object

Having this interfaces

```
interface DashletOne {
  property1: string;
  property2: string;
  property3: string;
}

interface DashletTwo {
  property4: string;
  property5: string;
}

interface Props {
  dashletOne: DashletOne;
  dashletTwo: DashletTwo;
}
```

I set this property

```
const properties: Props = {
  dashletOne: {
    property1: "string",
    property2: "string",
    property3: "string",
  },
  dashletTwo: {
    property4: "string",
    property5: "string",
  }
};
```

And in the view for example I refer it as `properties.dashletOne.property1`

What is the recommended way to group properties of a class?

Comment: This one is good enough. It all depends on the requirements. Keeping many things in mind like Are the properties finite? Are they dynamic? Will they change frequently? Does any api response change them? Does some dom events affect their states? Etc.

Comment: In my projects there are multiple divs, charts, cards which are dynamic so I use associative arrays for them and set them on ngOnInit then loop the data in html. It makes the pre processing a big complicated in terms of the data structure but it does the trick and maintenance becomes easy in case of changes and updates. Sometimes I make Map<> also.